# Finding the tangent line through the origin confused

Tags: calculus

For what value of x does the line tangent to $y=2^x$ through the origin? Give both exact values, and an approximation to $3$ places after the decimal.

I got as far as getting the derivative of $y=2^x$. I believe it's $\ln(2)(2^x)$. Now my question is do I just substitute the point $(0,0)$ into the point slope form?

Comment: I saw now your method is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the tangent line to $y=2^x$ at the point $(a,2^a)$.

Use your derivative calculation to write the equation of this tangent line (the slope and y-intercept will depend on $a$).

Now, take the expression for the $y$-intercept and set it equal to zero.

Solve for $a$, and you'll have it.

Answer (score 2):

The line is given to pass through origin, and it also tangent at some point $(x_1, y_1)$.

Now the line simply is $$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1} = \frac{d y}{dx} |_{(x_1, y_1)}\\
\frac{2^x - 2^{x_1}}{x-x_1} = 2^{x_1} \ln(2)$$

Since line passes through $(0,0)$, this point satisfies the line. Solving it will lead to:
$$x_1=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write down equation of line:

$$y-y_0=k(x-x_0)$$

Substitute $0$ for $y_0$ and $x_0$ as line passes through origin. $y$ here is your function $2^x$ and $k$ is $(2^x)$. You just need to solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the slope of the tangent must satisfy $f'(x_0)=f(x_0)/x_0$, i.e., $x_0\cdot f'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.  Having solved that equation the equation of the tangent line is $y=f'(x_0)\cdot x$.

From $x_0\cdot f'(x_0)=f(x_0)$, in our case $x_0\cdot2^{x_0}\ln(2)=2^{x_0}$ we gain $x_0=1/\ln(2)$, hence $f'(x_0)=e\cdot\ln(2))$ and the equation of the tangent line is $y=e\cdot\ln(2)x$.